# Opening GZ Object with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, gzip, logging

I haven't found similar queries, so quick question. Can you use any GZIP functions or such with PHP to read a GZIP object.

I'm basically using Amazon S3 class to get the .GZ logs, and I'm trying to parse whilst it's a loaded object, as opposed to downloading it to local and then parsing.

Is this not possible? Should I only be trying to download and parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Zlib extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) you can open and write gzip compressed files on the fly.

You need to save gz file and open it with gzfile() function.

Like this

```
$file = gzfile('log.gz');
foreach ($file as $line) {
    // read it line by line
}
```

Comment: Hi Osman, Thanks for your reply but as I say the files are being loaded as Objects via the S3 class to getObject. So I'm looking to do this WITHOUT resaving or opening up their access via HTTP.